# How to add a greater than symbol (>) to command prompt in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm coding an interactive CLI application in Node.js. I use `process.stdin.resume()` to continue reading `stdin` stream. But its command prompt doesn't have any symbols at the beginning:

```
$ node start.js
Welcome! Type a command:
  < *no symbols here*
```

How can I add a `>` symbol to have such a prompt:

```
$ node start.js
Welcome! Type a command:
>
```

Comment: Wrap your command in quotes. "<"

Comment: @BrandonSmith he's asking how to make his program print out ">" as a prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. As simple as that. You should just add `EOL + >` to the last `stdout` string:

```
stdout.write('Welcome! Type a command:' + EOL + '> ');
```

The result is:

```
$ node start.js
Welcome! Type a command:
>
```

`EOL` is from `os` module:

```
var os = require('os');
var EOL = os.EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) to do this. It can also help make your interactive CLI journey much simpler.

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
  .delimiter('>')
  .show();

vorpal.log('Welcome! Type a command:');
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote Vorpal.*